# Probability distribution vs. union doesn't hold?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My probabilities textbook gives me this theorem:

For any event $E$, the probability $P(E)$ is determined by the distribution $m$ by:

$$\sum_{w \in E}^{} m(w)$$

for every $E \subset \Omega$, and every event is $E$ is non-negative and $E$ is a subset of the sample space.

We also know that:

$$P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$

I know that (for example, a coin toss), Both theorems are equal to each other (since A and B are disjoint, i.e. we can't have heads and tails in one situation). However, consider this question:

The probability of a child having a laptop is $\frac{2}{3}$, the probability of him having a desktop is $\frac{4}{9}$ and the probability of having both is $\frac{1}{3}$. What is the probability of the student having either?

Using the first theorem: The sub sample space is $E = (L, D)$
Then $P(E)$ by the summation is $\frac{2}{3} + \frac{4}{9}$ which is obviously wrong since it is $> 1$

The "correct" answer is $P(L \cup D)$, but how come this theorem is wrong or doesn't work or am I using it wrong? I "think" (however, the book doesn't say this), that it only works for disjoint events (since in the summation we are potential counting those who have a laptop and desktop twice). In that case, how do I know when the theorem works (the book says it should hold for any event $E$).

Comment: Your misinterpreting the first "theorem" (in fact, that's a definition): using your notation, $L$ and $D$ are not elementary outcomes (each single student, or child, would be), the $L$ and $D$ are events and they are not disjoint.  In the second theorem (exclusion-inclusion) the $L$ and $D$ would be the $A$ and $B$.

Comment: $E=\{L\cap D, L\cap D^c, L^c\cap D,L^c\cap D^c\}$, not $E=\{L,D\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The favoured event, $E$, is not the set of $L$ and $D$; which is $\{L, D\}$.   $E$ is the *union* of those events.   $E = L\cup D$.

Otherwise, how would you represent the event of having both?

---

Events are sets of outcomes.

In this particular probability space, the events $L$ and $D$ contain outcomes (the $\omega$) which are *the ownership status of each individual student*.   Because some students may own both laptops and desktops, the events $L$ and $D$ have *common* outcomes.   So the sum of the measures in the union is the sum of the measures of each set minus the sum of the measures of their intersection.   Hence :

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(L\cup D) & = \sum_{\omega\in L\cup D} \mu(\omega)
\\ & = \sum_{\omega\in L} \mu(\omega) + \sum_{\omega\in D} \mu(\omega) - \sum_{\omega\in L\cap D} \mu(\omega)\\ & = \mathsf P(L)+\mathsf P(D)-\mathsf P(L\cap D)\end{align}$$